# Problema con una peticion en Sql Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Hola estoy haciendo una WebApp en C# hago esta petición a SqlServer y tengo un error pero al ejecutar esta consulta

```
public static int fn_insertaActualizaPaginas(int ai_codigoPagina, int ai_codigoPerfil, bool ab_estaActivo)
    {
        int li_respuesta = 0;
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Metodo.dameConexionBDD);
                con.Open();

                {
                    String sql = " BEGIN " +
                                 "  MERGE SI_MENU_PERFIL AS Target " +
                                 "  USING ( SELECT @CODIGO_PUS CODIGO_PUS, " +
                                                 " @CODIGO_PAG CODIGO_PAG, " +
                                                 " @ESTAACTIVO_MPE ESTAACTIVO_MPE " +
                                             " ) AS Source " +
                                     " ON (Target.CODIGO_PUS = Source.CODIGO_PUS AND Target.CODIGO_PAG = Source.CODIGO_PAG) " +
                                     " WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                                         " UPDATE SET Target.ESTAACTIVO_MPE = Source.ESTAACTIVO_MPE " +
                                     " WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN " +
                                         " INSERT (CODIGO_PUS, CODIGO_PAG, ESTAACTIVO_MPE) " +
                                         " VALUES (Source.CODIGO_PUS, Source.CODIGO_PAG, Source.ESTAACTIVO_MPE); " +
                                 " END ";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODIGO_PUS", SqlDbType.Int).Value= ai_codigoPerfil;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODIGO_PAG", SqlDbType.Int).Value= ai_codigoPagina;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ESTAACTIVO_MPE", SqlDbType.Bit).Value= ab_estaActivo;

                    li_respuesta = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());

                    if (ai_codigoPagina > 0)
                        li_respuesta = ai_codigoPagina;
                }
                con.Close();
                ts.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
        return li_respuesta;
    }
```

Obtengo ese error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en WebApiInventario.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>   Instrucción MERGE en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK_SI_MENU__REFERENCE_SI_PERFI". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "NUOImpresion", tabla "dbo.SI_PERFIL_USUARIO", column 'CODIGO_PUS'.**

Comment: El usuario que estas ingresando si existe como registro en las tablas que estas utilizando?

Comment: Hola. El mensaje es muy claro. Te falta rellenar alguna clave foránea en la tabla